# Overlay two seaborn barplots of different size

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Say there are two datasets: a big "background" set, and much smaller "foreground" set.  The foreground set comes from the background, but might be much smaller.

I am interested in showing the entire background distribution in an ordered `sns.barplot`, and have the foreground set a brighter contrasting color to draw attention to these samples.

The best solution I could find is to display one graph on top of the other, but what happens is the graph shrinks down to the smaller domain.  Here's what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)

# states of interest
txcahi = crashes[crashes['abbrev'].isin(['TX','CA','HI'])]

# Plot the total crashes
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
sns.barplot(y="total", x="abbrev", data=crashes, label="Total", color="lightgray")

# overlay special states onto gray plot as red bars
sns.barplot(y="total", x="abbrev", data=txcahi, label="Total", color="red")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

This data produces:
[image]

But it should look like this (ignore stylistic differences):
[image]

Why doesn't this approach work, and what would be a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seaborn `barplot` just plots the its `n` data along the values of `0` to `n-1`. If instead you'd use a matplotlib `bar` plot, which is unit aware (from matplotlib 2.2 onwards), it'll work as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)

# states of interest
txcahi = crashes[crashes['abbrev'].isin(['TX','CA','HI'])]

# Plot the total crashes
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)

plt.bar(height="total", x="abbrev", data=crashes, label="Total", color="lightgray")
plt.bar(height="total", x="abbrev", data=txcahi, label="Total", color="red")

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

[image]